# Ruby load does not see static methods in the class

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.4

I am experimenting with ruby (2.4.1p111) and with the load method and it does have some strange behavior:

I have two files:

*mytest.rb*:

```
class MyClass

  def self.greet(param)
   puts "Got called: #{param}"
  end

  greet 'Called locally'

  load "./testld.rb"
end
```

and the loaded file:

*testld.rb*:

```
greet 'Called by load'
```

I understood from documentation that the loaded code from *testld.rb* and the method call right in the *MyClass* should behave the same. Instead, I am getting:

```
-bash-4.2$ ruby mytest.rb
Got called: Called locally
/Blacksmith/RB/testld.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `greet' 
for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from mytest.rb:9:in `load'
    from mytest.rb:9:in `<class:MyClass>'
    from mytest.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Could you point to the documentation that left you with such understanding? That is not how it works. If it was enclosed in `MyClass` in `testld.rb`, it will be called as if it was. If it was not, it will not, no matter where you load it.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-load


I wrongly assumed the loaded code is executed in the context of the MyClass. MyClass.greet does the work as @MatayoshiMariano has pointed out.

Comment: @Pavel "I wrongly assumed the loaded code is executed in the context of the MyClass." That is not what MatayoshiMariano pointed out. That answer misses the point.

Comment: @Pavel you want something like `eval File.read('testld.rb')` but `load` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Pavel, I couldn't see how you got this interpretation. I agree that Ruby's namespacing is one of it's weaker points, but it's not as terrible as for `load` to perform a copy-paste. xd

Comment: @ndn I got  to this usecase by reading a book 'Learning Sinatra', where this is used exactly the way I posted the non-working code. They use it to call the static Sinatra::Base get method, by loading the calls from external file, routes.rb. They use ruby 2.0.0, so this may be the differentiator, I will test it with this version.

Comment: @Pavel, I'm pretty sure that is not how it works for any version of Ruby. Maybe 1.8.7-, but doubt it. Still, Sinatra has "DSL version" and "namespaced version". If you directly do `require 'sinatra'`, you will be able to use stuff like `get` and `post` without explicit receiver. This includes in files that you loaded after `require 'sinatra'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `MyClass.greet` in `testld.rb`, that is because `greet` is a class method defined in the class `MyClass`.

[Here](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/113-class-variables) is documentation for class methods.

Comment: @Pavel The fact that it works is coincidence. This answer is irrelevant to your actual question.

Comment: Is anything mentioned in this answer specific to Ruby 2.4, whose tag MatayoshiMariano added to the suggested edit?

Comment: @sawa I do not think that is a coincidince, but my answer may be incomplete, it's missing what `load` does.
I added the ruby-2.4 tag because @Pavel says that he is using `ruby 2.4.1p111`

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you load a file, the loaded file is always evaluated within the main environment. The value of `self` in the main environment of `testld.rb` is the main environment of the entire script. Hence, your

```
greet 'Called by load'
```

is not equivalent to

```
MyClass.greet 'Called by load'
```

as you expected.

Comment: What I really wanted to achieve is to have the static method called, the 
MyClass.greet. 

I thought that the load works kind of like a C preprocessor, placing the file content into the MyClass and then execute, which was wrong.

Comment: You do have defined `MyClass.greet`. That part, you did correctly. What you did wrong is the way you called it. And here is the explanation to it.

Comment: @Pavel Don't think of Ruby as a fancy C. It's Smalltalk in origin which has a different approach to solving problems like this. If you created a `module` and `include` it in your class you'll be able to hook in through the `included` method and everything should work seamlessly.

Comment: @Pavel: `load`, `require`, and `require_relative` simply run the file. That's all they do.